# Indexing is not working in Object array in c#

Tags: c#

I have an `Object[]`, My goal is to achieve Indexing.
Example:

```
string objectPath = "RiskItems[#0].Coverages[#1].QuestionAnswer[#2]";
object[] indexes = new Object[] { 8 };
var expResult = "RiskItems[8].Coverages[1].QuestionAnswer[2]";
var result = Tokenizer.Path(objectPath, indexes);
```

The Path Method is:

```
public static string Path(string objectPath, object[] indexes)
    {
        string str = objectPath;
        if (indexes != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
            {
                string val = indexes[i] is int ? indexes[i].ToString() : "'" + indexes[i] + "'";
                str = str.Replace("#" + i, val);
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

From the above my expected result is not same as the result returned by the `Path` method.
Can any one suggest me regarding the logic in Path method to achieve my goal please.
Also I am restricted to use this format, So I cannot use string.format

Comment: You're using `#1` as your token, but your array only has 1 element and is zero-based, so `#1` will never be replaced, only `#0` will be replaced.

Comment: So to achieve this, an you suggest me some changes in the path method

Comment: I think @Diado rather means you should change the `ProdEffDates[#1]` to `ProdEffDates[#0]`

Comment: Well, as you have been told that the index is 1 out - how about adding 1 when you are creating the replace string.

Comment: how would this code handle indexes of #10 or #100? Also your edited path is 0 based, so it works as expected. Your initial question is simply using the wrong input. Is there any reason why you wouldn't simply want to use string.Format instead, where you could create `string.Format("ProdEffDates[{0}]", indexes )`?

Comment: In your edit - you have a working example - just match what is replaced there in your example that doesn't work - #0 is replaced by first object in array, #1 by 2nd & #2 by 3rd.

Comment: Does this should change to achieve my goal
object[] indexes = new Object[] { 8 };

Comment: @Meena you are not making much sense of the information given in the comments. This leads me to believe that you don't really know what your code is actually doing. As a side question, are you stuck to the format you are showing, or are you capable of changing it to the format where you could use the .net string.Format method instead?

Comment: @Icepickle Yes I am stuck to use that format

Comment: My final goal is 
Input :
RiskItems[#0].Coverages[#1].QuestionAnswer[#2]
new Object[] { 8 }
Output should be
RiskItems[8].Coverages[1].QuestionAnswer[2]

Comment: @Icepickle I have Edited my whole question as per the final goal. Please check

Comment: That's not a small change, and it also completely changes the validity of your path code. I had an answer for you, but it can pretty much be discarted with your latest update, however, now it would work if your path method would simply remove the # before returning the end result to a consumer

Comment: If you are wondering why it got undeleted, after you deleted your question, I could still see it partly and I asked a [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389590/3231537). I didn't ask it to be undeleted though, but it seems some people thought it was worth to bring this question back. I did put a lot of work in the answer here, so if it did work, please mark it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this code in the updated question

```
string objectPath = "RiskItems[#0].Coverages[#1].QuestionAnswer[#2]";
object[] indexes = new Object[] { 8 };
var expResult = "RiskItems[8].Coverages[1].QuestionAnswer[2]";
var result = Tokenizer.Path(objectPath, indexes);
```

Your path method doesn't work correctly, because it will only change the `#0` token, but it will leave `#1` and `#2` alone, leaving you with `RiskItems[8].Coverages[#1].QuestionAnswer[#2]`.

So, to fix that, you should just remove the left over `#` characters before returning the result, namely

```
public static string Path(string objectPath, object[] indexes)
{
    string str = objectPath;
    if (indexes != null)
    {
        for (int i = indexes.Length; --i >= 0; )
        {
            if (indexes[i] is int intValue) {
               str = str.Replace( $"[#{i}]", $"[{intValue}]" );
               continue;
            }
            str = str.Replace( $"[#{i}]", $"['{indexes[i]}']" );
        }
    }
    // remove any left over tokens
    return str.Replace("#", "");
}
```

The updated code would also fix any higher indexes than #9.

You can verify this code on a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPYWcJ)

## this part of the answer was for the following [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58009694/3)

The code you supplied does mostly what you expect it to do, it will go through your indexes and it will replace the numbers `0` to `9` which are prepended with `#`, however nothing above `#9` will work, which is due to the replace method (see a more detailed work around below).

What you are currently not getting, is that your expected result is incorrect based on the data given. Indexes are 0 based in arrays, and you want to get index 1, so the second item. But you are only supplying 1 value.

To make your test work, you have 2 options:

- Change the path to: `string objectPath = "ProdEffDates[#0]";`
- Change your indexes to: `object[] indexes = new Object[] { 0, 8 };`

In both suggestions a correction is made that would handle the problem you have, at least, until you run up to having to replace and index at #10. That is because it will first replace `#1` before hitting `#10`, which would then be replaced with whatever value was at `#1`.

To handle those problems, you have again a few options :)

- Replace based on a more predictable format, like

  ```
   str = str.Replace( $"[#{i}]", $"{indexes[i]}" )
  ```
- Iterate from `indexes.length - 1` to `0`, thus ensuring you replace the bigger numbers before the smaller numbers ;)
- Use regex replacements